# Which PHP compression method is better?

Tags: php, compression, deflate

I'm working at a PHP system using Yii Framework.
I have a large ammount of plain text, and need to store this data on a Postgres' Database.
I've made a little research and found these two functions: **gzdeflate** and **gzcompress**.
I couldn't see a big difference of performance and results between these functions.

Do you guys can tell me if there is expressive difference between them? BTW, am I in the right path? Compressing plain text before putting it on the database is the best solution to save bandwidth and space on disk?

Comment: Unless you have benchmarked a *critically positive* performance use-case, **don't compress manually**. HTTP will compress automatically (with any sane server configuration), and "compressing" small text can even be harmful. Compressed information also must be dealt with specially - and unless there is a *good need* it just makes the data in the database hard to deal with. (Transparent automatic compression in a database engine is a different matter, but the key is - it is *not* manual compression.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not compress or otherwise encode text before putting it in the database unless you are ***110% positive*** that you will **never** need to perform anything other than simple storage and retrieval on it. If you think you might ever need to issue a SELECT based on something contained in that text you're going to be completely hosed.

That said, if you plan on storing large amounts of data in a DB table many DBMSes have transparent compression built in. Eg: [MySQL's InnoDB compression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-compression.html)

Lastly, the difference between compress and deflate is negligible IMO. Just remember to never set the compression level to 9 unless you want your CPU to burst into flames for no raisin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Transparent compression really looks a good solution.
How can I configure it in a Postgres' table?

Answer (score 0):

Well, between these two, **gzdeflate** seems to have a better compression rate. I've done some tests and didn't find a significant difference on time execution. and Yes, it always a good ideia using compression when you need to reduce space usage and band usage.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022677/php-is-gzdeflate-safe-across-multiple-machines/15028347#15028347).  `gzdeflate` does not produce the zlib header and trailer around the deflate data the `gzcompress` does, and so the result will always be six bytes shorter.  However it then loses an important integrity check.  Use `gzcompress`.